# Load Image in tkinter with threading shows 'pyimage2' doesn't exist

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to load 2 images in my app, first in Main window and second in a thread.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time

def foo():
    global root
    root = Tk()
    img1 = PhotoImage(file='Logo.png')
    lable1 = Label(root, image = img1).pack()
    threading.Thread(target=bar).start()
    root.mainloop()

def bar():
    app = Tk()
    app.withdraw()
    time.sleep(5)
    app.deiconify()
    root.withdraw()
    img2 = PhotoImage(file='./images/night_bulb.png')
    lable3 = Label(app, image= img2).pack()
    lable2 = Label(app, text='Starting Count now...').pack()
    app.mainloop()

foo()
```

This Produces the following output:

```
"C:\Users\Samaksh Gupta\PycharmProjects\myIDLE\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Samaksh Gupta/PycharmProjects/myIDLE/test.py"
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Samaksh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Samaksh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Samaksh Gupta/PycharmProjects/myIDLE/test.py", line 20, in bar
    lable3 = Label(app, image= img2).pack()
  File "C:\Users\Samaksh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3143, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\Samaksh Gupta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2567, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

How do I add image in both the windows?

Comment: It is because you have two instances of `Tk()`.  Use `Toplevel()` instead inside `bar()`.  Also `mainloop()` cannot be executed in a thread, so remove `app.mainloop()`.  Final you need to save the reference of `img2`, otherwise it will be garbage collected.  Actually you should not use thread to run `bar()`, use `after()`.

Comment: @acw1668 I tried that. Now the window opens and no error comes. But the image doesn't load too. Its just the Label that shows up.

Comment: As I said *"you need to save the reference of img2, otherwise it will be garbage collected"*.

Comment: @acw1668 I need to use thread in my main app. When the tk loads, it has tons of images and animated gifs that the window hangs for 7-10 secs. I need another window to display with message 'Loading' and a Image. In that 7-10 sec duration, my app window remains hidden with `withdraw` command.

Comment: @acw1668 Sorry, saw your edit after refreshing page. How to save the reference of img2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have two instances of `Tk()`.  Use `Toplevel()` instead inside `bar()`.

Also `mainloop()` cannot be executed in a thread, so remove `app.mainloop()` from `bar()`.

Final you need to keep a reference of `img2`, otherwise it will be garbage collected.

Below is updated code based on yours:

```py
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time

def foo():
    global root
    root = Tk()
    img1 = PhotoImage(file='Logo.png')
    lable1 = Label(root, image=img1).pack()
    threading.Thread(target=bar).start()
    root.mainloop()

def bar():
    time.sleep(5)
    root.withdraw()
    app = Toplevel()
    app.withdraw()
    img2 = PhotoImage(file='./images/night_bulb.png')
    label3 = Label(app, image=img2)
    label3.pack()
    label3.image = img2  # keep a reference to avoid garbage collection
    Label(app, text='Starting Count now...').pack()
    app.deiconify()

foo()
```

Comment: @SamakshGupta I don't have the issue after adding `time.sleep(5)` below `root = Tk()` in `foo()`.